# Delimiting regions of influence for ports

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, region

I have datasets containing origin-destin (ports) and volumes for trade data.

From these datasets, I can extract points of origins that are related to only a particular port. Interpolating such data, I can generate the images below, which show the "area of influence" of a particular port.

Now, I want to merge all of these rasters, in order to create some sort of what I believe would look like a series of "watersheds" delimiting the area of influence for the different ports

How can I "merge" these different areas in a single map, with all the multiple regions? Is it possible?

[image: Area of influence, where a particular variable is observed]

[image]

Comment: Is this in QGIS or ArcGis? You've got both tags... it seems to me you want to merge your points and then perform your raster operation (which looks like IDW). Another viable option is to mosaic, sum or mean the raster depending on whether the points in set B replaces, adds to or is similar data from a different source. Can you explain more about your points, where they came from and your raster operation please.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson? i have updated the question to answer your question. By the way, I have both softwares. So I can use either one to solve this issue.

Comment: So, does each set of points represent a commodity and its source? Are the units the same for each (ie. tons, dollars, rubles, containers)? If you have the same units you can merge the points before interpolating or sum/mean the rasters afterward - but if the units are different you risk over/under representing commodities.

Answer (score 1):

As your question is a bit fuzzy i only can try to give an answer based on interpretation.

Assuming that you want to merge both raster datasets, I would suggest to use Raster Calculator in QGIS.

[image]

Either you sum up the values by using the statement

```
raster1 + raster2
```

or you calculate the mean with

```
(raster1 + raster2)/2
```

Another way would be to merge the two point datasets before interpolating. For this task you could use the "Merge shapefiles to one" tool

[image]

Comment: And how can I then plot the different regions of influence?

Comment: This was my interpretation after your previous description of your problem. After you have updated it, I can at least understand what the two datasets show, but still it is a bit complicated to see what you're aiming at. Can you describe in a few more words what the final map should show? It would be helpful to show some examples of the input data.

Comment: and to show us a legend to the two maps.